# Issue with .toISOString() function

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code HTML + JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display a date after changing the hours, minutes, and seconds.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script>
 function myFunction()
  {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  document.write(d + '<br/>');
  document.write('ISO Date '+ d.toISOString() + '<br/>');
  //I want it to be 2013-04-17T00:00:00.000Z
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**:

```
Thu Apr 18 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
ISO Date 2013-04-17T18:30:00.000Z
```

Could anyone help on understanding this difference in Date & Time

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(-12, d.getTimezoneOffset(), 0, 0); //removing the timezone offset and 12 hours
console.log(d.toISOString()); //2013-04-17T00:00:00.000Z
```

I don't know, why would you need a ISO date a day earlier, but in case it is a typo:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0, -d.getTimezoneOffset(), 0, 0); //removing the timezone offset.
console.log(d.toISOString()); //2013-04-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: In the second example, I believe that it should be `d.getTimezoneOffset()`. The offset can be negative or positive. The negation will create an addition if the value is negative.

Comment: @dbasch thats the point. If the value is negative, then you are **behind** UTC0, so you need to add the hours to your local time.

Answer (score 4):

```
2013-18-04 00:00:00 GMT+0530
2013-17-04 18:30:00 GMT+0000
```

These are the two timestamps. The first one has a time zone, the second one is GMT (no time zone adjustment). If you take the second timestamp and add `05:30:00` to `18:30:00` you get midnight of the following day. That matches the first timestamp.

Comment: Worth noting the comment within OP's code: `//I want it to be 2013-04-17T00:00:00.000Z`. I think he's looking for a way to prevent `.toISOString()` converting from GMT+0530 to GMT+0000.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: You are right... I got the answer from Artyom Neustroev i.e. removing the timezone offset. any way thanks to everyone for your time

Comment: Those "GMT" suffixes aren't time zones, but offsets. They tell you nothing about daylight saving time adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can remove timezone like this:

```
let birthday = new Date(this.profile.birthday + ' UTC').toISOString();
```