# JavaScript - changing hours, when converting in ISO format

Tags: javascript, date

So, I need to convert this kind of Date in ISO format:

```
"05-Mar-13 17:00:00.000000"
```

But when I do something like this:

```
var Time = (new Date("05-Mar-13 17:00:00.000000")).toISOString().replace('Z', Milliseconds);
```

I've got in variable Time another hour:

```
"2013-03-05T16:00:00.000000"
```

So It changes on another hour.
What should I do to avoid this changing of hours?

Comment: `toIsoString()` does not deal with your time zone offset. Here's help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084313/issue-with-toisostring-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISO format is supposed to convert the time to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times).

Your browser supposes that the time you are passing the Date constructor is based on your local time, supposedly one hour behind UTC.

To counter this, you can use

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

which will return the time offset in minutes. In your case it will return `-60`.

A complete example:

```
function getTime() {
    var date = new Date("05-Mar-13 17:00:00.000000")
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
    return date.toISOString();
}
```

Note that this can set time minutes to a negative value, but the `Date` object is smart enough to convert that to a new time with positive minutes again by changing the hour.

Comment: Notice that I of course only have tested this in one timezone, but I belive it should work for all timezones.